# log compression using logrotate

Tags: logs, compression, logrotate, jboss

I was trying to set compression for `jboss` log files. The log files I want to compress are `console.log` and `server.log`. Compression for `console.log` is working fine, but `server.log` I am seeing issues. I am using `logrotate` for using compression . Please find my rules below .

```
$cat /etc/logrotate.d/jboss 
 /data/logs/*/console.log
 /data/logs/*/server.log {
 daily
 rotate 14
 copytruncate
 compress
 missingok
 postrotate
  # Service restarts go here.
 endscript
```

}

log files are named as follows

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs      139 Dec 21 03:23 console.log-20151221.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs 12195934 Dec 21 23:59 server.log.2015-12-21
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs     1383 Dec 22 03:40 console.log-20151222.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs 12157917 Dec 22 23:59 server.log.2015-12-22
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs     1037 Dec 23 03:32 console.log-20151223.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs 11966496 Dec 23 23:59 server.log.2015-12-23
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs      142 Dec 24 03:10 console.log-20151224.gz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jboss logs      113 Dec 24 12:27 console.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 jboss logs  8730030 Dec 24 17:35 server.log
```

Please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

`jboss` is rotating the log `server.log` itself. You can see the different timestamps on the logs where `console.log` is rotated around 3.10am and `server.log` around midnight. Also the filename notation differ. If you want to use compression, I suggest to disable rotation within `jboss` and to use `logrotate` instead.

Comment: I am using logrotate itself . Compression is working for console.log but not for server.log . there is .gz extension for console.log files.

Comment: You 'configured' logrotate for both but `logrotate` only get its 'hands' on `console.log`. `server.log` is being rotated by `jboss` before `logrotate` can do its job.